# Recognizing tetris pieces in C

Tags: c, image, image-processing

I have to make an application that recognizes inside an black and white image a piece of tetris given by the user. I read the image to analyze into an array.

How can I do something like this using C?

Comment: Where do the images come from? How are they created? Can they be any size, or is there a fixed size?

Comment: What does the image look like? A photo? Or is it perfect - four white pixels per tetris piece? Bigger? 16x16 pixels each block of the piece? Parallel to the image edges or rotated?

Comment: To answer to all quetions please consult this file: http://ruifelgueiras.net76.net/Work/work.doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you already loaded the images into arrays, what about using regular expressions?
You don't need exact shape matching but approximately, so why not give it a try!

*Edit*: I downloaded your doc file. You must identify a random pattern among random figures on a 2D array so regex isn't suitable for this problem, lets say that's the bad news. The good news is that your homework is not *exactly* image processing, and it's much easier.

It's your homework so I won't create the code for you but I can give you directions.

1. You need a routine that can create a new piece from the original pattern/piece rotated. (note: with piece I mean the 4x4 square - all the cells of it)
2. You need a routine that checks if a piece matches an area from the 2D image at position x,y - the matching area would have corners (x-2, y-2, x+1, y+1).
3. You search by checking every image position (x,y) for a match.

Since you must use parallelism you can create 4 threads and assign to each thread a different rotation to search.

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I’ll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems. -Jamie Zawinski

Comment: Very clever Jem. It's pattern recognition problem. It's a homework. When are we supposed to use Regex?

Comment: How can I use regular expressions in this problem?

Comment: You can *see* each piece as an array (unfolded) with 'filled' end 'empty' cells.
For example the 'bar' will be like "__ooooo__oo__ooo__ooooooo_".
The 'square' will be like "__ooooooo__o_", and so on.
As you see, I'm looking for patterns and not the exact number of feeled or empty cells.

Comment: Maybe I'll post a concrete example. But you can see that just by counting the repeated patterns you can identify the pieces. If 2 pieces are alike you can use a second regex pattern.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand that "__oooo__ooo".
What does that means?

Answer (score 1):

You might not want to implement that from scratch (unless required, of course) ... I'd recommend looking for a suitable library. I've heard that [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV) is good, but never done any work with machine vision myself so I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 1):

Search for connected components (i.e. using depth-first search; you might want to avoid recursion if efficiency is an issue; use your own stack instead). The largest connected component should be your tetris piece. You can then further analyze it (using the shape, the size or some kind of border description)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the shapes given for tetris pieces in Wikipedia, called "I,J,L,O,S,T,Z", it seems that the ratios of the sides of the bounding box (easy to find given a binary image and C) reveal whether you have I (4:1) or O (1:1); the other shapes are 2:3.

To detect which of the remaining shapes you have (J,L,S,T, or Z), it looks like you could collect the length and position of the shape's edges that fall on the bounding box's edges.  Thus, T would show 3 and 1 along the 3-sides, and 1 and 1 along the 2 sides.  Keeping track of the positions helps distinguish J from L, S from Z.